# Extjs Grid panel scroll bar disappear on resize

Tags: extjs4.1

I am struggling with this issue from past couple of days, any help / pointers greatly appreciated.

I created a MainPanel (Ext.panel.Panel) with fit layout. MainPanel contains two panels (searchPanel, ResultsPanel)

```
MainPanel {
    layout: 'fit',
    region : 'center',
    items : [{ 
        layout: 'border'
        items : [
            searchPanel,
            resultsPanel
        ]
    ]
```

SearchPanel is a regular panel(region: center) and resultsPanel(region: south) is GridPanel with resizable set to true. After doing my search i see the results in the gridPanel with both scrollbars enabled. Couple of issues when i maximize my MainPanel

1. ResultsPanel does not completely expand to the max window size. (I have to drag to the max size).
2. If i do that then on restore my scrollbar's disappear.

Is there something i need to do on gridpanel so that i wont loose the scrollbars on restore and on maximize the grid panel should expand to max window size. Thanks for help

Rishi

Comment: lots of answers below, any that were helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can not put multiple items in a fit layout. Fit layout is for a single component to take size of the parent component.

You need an auto/anchor layout or a vbox. Check the layout browser in examples for something that resembles what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It used to work in the earlier versions but not any more. Have HBox/VBox Layout.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you provided contains a few errors, so I'm assuming that you have one main panel fitting the whole browser's viewport or anything else "around" the main panel and the 2 other panels that fill that main panel.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    itemId: 'mainPanel',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items : [{
        itemId: 'searchPanel',
        ...
    }, {
        flex: 1,
        itemId: 'resultsPanel',
        ...
    }]
});
```

This generates a searchPanel with the height that it needs for the contents (form fields) and a resultsPanel that fills up the remaining space.

Please note that I just added the itemId properties to clarify which item is what. You don't need them.

If this answers your question, please note that you had one level of nesting too many and used a border layout (which is only useful if you know the height of the "north" panel).